# db2 linux console client

Tags: mysql, linux, client, db2

How would I execute a sql script on a remote db2 server?

In MySQL I would have done something like this:

```
mysql -uroot -proot -h localhost < resources/db_scripts/drop_mysql.sql >> logs/drop_my.log
```

I would also like to do the same for MSSQL and Sybase.

Comment: Maybe if you remove the second `>>`, this will work. But for `MSSQL` and `Sybase` you don't need just a feature, but completely different tools.

Comment: nonono this is an example for mysql, but I need tool for db2...

Comment: Well, if you want one tool to do it all, Perl DBI shell probably comes closest. Assuming there are DB2 drivers for DBI (I'd be shocked if there aren't)

Comment: that may be different tools i just need possibility to execute my sql scripts on different DBs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that type of operation in DB2 with the "Data Server client" (it had other names in previous DB2 versions, for example "DB2 Administration client"). This application has a set of tools that permit you to control a local or remote database. The most appropriated tool for your case is called the "Command Window".

In order to start working with remote database via the Command Window, you have to "see" the remote databases, and for this, you catalog a remote machine (catalog admin node), a remote instance (catalog node) and then the database (catalog database). It looks complicated, and to prevent this problem, there is a graphical tool called the DB2 Configure assistant (db2ca) that permits you to configure the DB2 environment.

```
db2 catalog admin tcpip node NODENAME remote SERVERNAME SYSTEM SERVERNAME
db2 catalog tcpip node INSTNAME remote SERVERNAME server PORTNUM remote_instance INSTANCE system SERVERNAME;
db2 catalog database DBNAME as ALIAS at node INSTNAME
```

Once you have catalog your remote database, you can do

```
db2 -tvf resources/db_scripts/drop_mysql.sql -z logs/drop_my.log
```

As part of your script file, you should have the connection statement (db2 connect to ALIAS user USERNAME using PASSWORD) or you have to establish the connection before call the execution of the script file.

Comment: I dont understand what is the NODENAME, and SERVERNAME SYSTEM SERVERNAME ?

Comment: Those are necessary elements to "catalog" server, instances and databases in a DB2 client. If you do not want to bother about them, try to use the "Configure Assistant"

Comment: Take a look at: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001944.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [db2 Command line processor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010412.html) as this:

$db2 "select * from table_xyz"

But I think you may need SSH access to remote server.